# Where can I find a place to upload m applets?

Tags: web-hosting, free

Good afternoon!

I am in a beginner java class and am currently learning about making applets. Chrome is not letting me run them locally (they do run in appletviewer no problem) and I would like to test them out in a proper browser.

Can anyone guide me to where I may be able to find free web hosting? It doesn't have to be anything fancy, it can have all the adds it wants, I am just looking for somewhere I can test stuff out.

p.s. It is my first time asking something in this forum, please excuse any ignorance I still have.

Comment: Have you considered using `localhost`? This means it can run on your own computer, but your browser will treat it as if it came over the web.

Comment: @TRiG - I did not even know that existed. Now to figure out how to properly set it up. Thank you very much!

Comment: Debian and derivatives: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`. Windows: XAMPP from Apache Friends.